# jQueryMobile: what version I have to use for my applications

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm a newbie to jQueryMobile. When I'm going through the documentation and sample, I'm seeing different versions are included in various samples like (jquery.mobile-1.0a1, jquery.mobile-1.0a2, jquery.mobile-1.0b2,....).

Now I'm in confusion that what version I have to use for my applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the latest stable build: http://jquerymobile.com/download.